# pass UIImage between UITabBarControllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

i'm trying to pass an `UIImage` from one `UIView` in `UITabBarController1` to another UIView in `UINavigationController` in `UITabBarController2`. In View1 i tried this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    UploadModifyViewController *view2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"modify"];
    UITabBarController *navBar = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navBar"];
    view2.imageView.image = image;                //<-----
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:navBar animated:YES];
}
```

Remember, view2 is in a NavigationController, and NavigationController is in a TabBarController. Extern Variable doesn't work, because these can't be used with UI Elements.

---

Posted this question [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/94351-pass-uiimage-between-viewcontrollers.html#post391397) too, but still no solution.
In this forum i posted a screenshot for better understanding from where to where i try to pass the image.

Comment: You haven't said what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

It probably doesn't work because the `imageView` outlet is still `nil` at the time you are accessing it. A view controller doesn't load its view unless it has to, and only when it loads its view from the NIB/storyboard will it connect the outlets.

You should declare a separate `UIImage` property in `UploadModifyViewController` that you can then use in this place to assign the image to. Then, in `UploadModifyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, assign the property's contents to the image view.

Comment: I already tried this, because my thoughts about the initialization were the same. I declared the `UIImage` in the `UploadModifyViewController.h` but this also doesn't work. Perhaps its something about the `@property` values? I set them to `(nonatomic, retain)`

Comment: Any other solutions? I have no idea to fix this